# Рекурсивная функция PHP

Tags: php

Цель: взять данные о всех товарах из складской системы. Написал рекурсивную функцию

```
function get_all_products($url, $fields, $assoc_total = array())
{
  $json = do_curl_request($url, $fields);
  $assoc = json_decode($json, true);
  $assoc_total = array_merge($assoc_total, $assoc['rows']);
  // echo '<br><br><br>';
  // var_dump($assoc_total);
  $next_href = $assoc['meta']['nextHref'];
  if ($next_href) {
    get_all_products($next_href, $fields, $assoc_total);
  }
  return $assoc_total;
}
```

Делаю вызов:

```
$url = 'https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product/?offset=1834&limit=1';
$fields = array();

$total = get_all_products($url, $fields);
echo '<br><br><br>';
echo '<br><br><br>';
var_dump($total);
```

Но в $total почему-то возвращается лишь первая итерация, при том, что $next_href истинно. Дебажил $assoc_total внутри самой функции (строки 6,7), последовательно выводит каждую итерацию.

Comment: Ну а внутренний вызов `get_all_products` возвращает данные куда? Правильно - в пустоту.

Comment: Кажется, я понял, к чему вы ведете. Но в каком месте поместить еще один return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По наводке [u_mulder](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178087/u-mulder) понял, что в функции не хватало всего лишь маленького штриха.

```
function get_all_products($url, $fields, $assoc_total = array())
{
  $json = do_curl_request($url, $fields);
  $assoc = json_decode($json, true);
  $assoc_total = array_merge($assoc_total, $assoc['rows']);
  // echo '<br><br><br>';
  // var_dump($assoc_total);
  $next_href = $assoc['meta']['nextHref'];
  if ($next_href) {
    $assoc_total = get_all_products($next_href, $fields, $assoc_total);
  }
  return $assoc_total;
}
```

Теперь результат рекурсии возвращается в переменную, и далее суммируется.